# Why is FNV1a hashing data one byte at the time?

Tags: performance, hash

I noticed some implementations of C++ std::hash use FNV1a algorithm, but this is language agnostic question.

One thing I find strange is that algorithm processes 1 byte of data per loop iteration.

```
   hash = FNV_offset_basis
   for each byte_of_data to be hashed
        hash = hash XOR byte_of_data
        hash = hash × FNV_prime
   return hash
```

I wonder why algorithm does not process 4 or 8 bytes of data per loop and fallback to per byte processing for  the last few bytes(if length of range is not multiple of 4 or 8).

Comment: algorithms are typically documented in their most basic form, with optimization being a task left up to implementations.

Comment: Actually if you have Visual Studio 2017 installed you will see it is not unrolled.